# Where I can find ngrok installation path?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, ngrok

I have run in my terminal:

```
pip3 install ngrok
```

Where did Ubuntu 18.04 installed it? I can't find it using `find -iname ngrok`

Comment: try command -  `locate ngrok`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the installation directory with:

```sh
pip3 show ngrok | grep Location
```

Output will probably be:
`/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages`